# How to change Apple watch table cell background?

Tags: background, tablecell, apple-watch

I am having trouble setting an image for a custom background for a apple watch table cell.

When I look at the interface.storyboard and the storyboard preview it displays the background image I have selected in the the inspector (a dark grey background with a vertical blue bar on the left).

However when I run the simulator no background is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that the color associated with the Group within your TableRowController does not have a set color. In your storyboard, select the Group, open the "Attributes" tab, and verify that "Color" is set to "Default" or "Clear Color".

I'd also suggest trying to set the background "Mode" to "Scale To Fill" to be sure that the image is being set and is viewable (although it may appear distorted - just a thought to be sure the image actually shows).

Attaching a screenshot of the Attributes inspector for clarity.
[image: Attributes Inspector]